# How to keep all records for the latest item in each group

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

I have an Oracle database where each row contains

- The number of the flight flown by a passenger (PLNR)
- The flight date (PLDATE)
- The ticket number for passengers (TKTNUM)

Example content:

```
PLNR    PLDATE      TKTNUM
100     10/01/2017  1234
100     11/01/2017  1235
100     11/01/2017  1236
200     9/01/2017   7890
200     10/01/2017  7891
200     10/01/2017  5678
```

I would like to keep all the ticket numbers in the latest flight for each flight number.

Example output:

```
PLNR    PLDATE      TKTNUM
100     11/01/2017  1235
100     11/01/2017  1236
200     10/01/2017  7891
200     10/01/2017  5678
```

I searched online and found several posts advising to use dense_rank and keep first, but I am struggling with combining multiple criteria (e.g., PLDATE and PLNR) to get multiple records.

Can you please suggest a solution and, more importantly, explain how it works? (I am getting in translation on this one).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT PLNR, PLDATE, TKTNUM
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         max(PLDATE) Over (Partition By PLNR) As dt
  FROM table
)
WHERE PLDATE = dt
```

Comment: may need to trunc PLDate()  I think oracle always records time  so depending on how the dates make it in, they may have a time component.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT PLNR, PLDATE, TKTNUM
                  , Dense_Rank ()Over (partition by PLNR, Trunc(PLDATE) order by PLDATE DESC) DR)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE DR= 1
```

a CTE or subquery is needed as the DR must materialize in memory before we can limit by it.

the `over` syntax is an analytical function which assigns a sequential rank for each partition (PLNR and trunc(PLDATE) ordered by date descending. Since We are using the dense_rank function same dates would be assigned the same value.  so the newest PLDate will always have a rank of 1 per plnr/PLDATE.

So the CTE Results in this:

```
PLNR    PLDATE      TKTNUM DR
100     10/01/2017  1234   2
100     11/01/2017  1235   1
100     11/01/2017  1236   1
200     9/01/2017   7890   2
200     10/01/2017  7891   1
200     10/01/2017  5678   1
```

and we only keep the 1's in the select against the CTE.

Now I used Trunc on PLDATE incase it contains a time component as we didn't want that messing stuff up; since oracle typically stores both if entered.